# Not able to generate the WSDL file of the Custom Apex SOAP Webservice

Tags: apex, soap

I am getting an issue while generating the WSDL for my custom SOAP Service. Earlier when I did back in 2018 I was able to generate the WSDL. Now, the issue that I am getting is when I click on generate WSDL then it generates the WSLD file for the whole org instead of that particular class only.

Below is my code

```
    global with sharing class AccountPlanner {
    
    webservice static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName){
        String greetMessage = 'Welcome '+firstName+' '+lastName;
        return greetMessage;
    }
    
    webservice static AccountWrapper createAccount(AccountWrapper accountRec){ 
    
        Account accRec = new Account();
        accRec.Name = accountRec.Name;
        accRec.Rating = accountRec.Rating;
        accRec.Industry = accountRec.Industry;
        accRec.Phone = accountRec.Phone;
        accRec.AccountNumber = accountRec.AccountNumber;
        
        insert accRec;
        Contact conRec = accountRec.contactRecord;
        conRec.AccountId = accRec.Id;
        insert conRec;
        
        return accountRec;
    }
    
    global class AccountWrapper {
    
        webservice String Name;
        webservice String Rating;
        webservice String Industry;
        webservice String Phone;
        webservice String AccountNumber;
        webservice Contact contactRecord;
        
    }

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you generating the wsdl? I just tested this in my org, and it works the same as it always has.

Comment: I was trying from the free developer edition. I tried the Mohit solution and it worked it was because of the reference of standard object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you are referencing an object "Contact" of Salesforce Schema in your parameter `accountRec` for `createAccount` method and hence all related Standard objects are pulled as a dependency in the WSDL.

You can easily get away with it by not referencing any SObject in the Wrapper definition you have for the method parameter.

Check the below-modified code

```
global with sharing class AccountPlanner {

 webservice static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName){
     String greetMessage = 'Welcome '+firstName+' '+lastName;
     return greetMessage;
  }

  webservice static AccountWrapper createAccount(AccountWrapper accountRec){ 

    AccountWrapper accountResponse = new AccountWrapper();

    Account accRec = new Account();
    accRec.Name = accountRec.Name;
    accRec.Rating = accountRec.Rating;
    accRec.Industry = accountRec.Industry;
    accRec.Phone = accountRec.Phone;
    accRec.AccountNumber = accountRec.AccountNumber;
    
    insert accRec;
    Contact conRec = new Contact();
    conRec.LastName = accountRec.contactLastName;
    conRec.AccountId = accRec.Id;
    insert conRec;
    
    accountResponse = accountRec;
    
    return accountResponse;
    
}

global class AccountWrapper {

    webservice String Name;
    webservice String Rating;
    webservice String Industry;
    webservice String Phone;
    webservice String AccountNumber;
    webservice String contactLastName;
    
   }
 
 }
```

Carefully note how my Wrapper does not have any reference to an SObject. If you need to pass in a lot of attributes I suggest creating a ContactWrapper class as well as a part of the definition. This way the WSDL will have no reference to any standard objects.

Comment: It worked thanks for the quick turn around :)